# Passing the Value to the Constructor from Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a custom controller used for VF page and in the controller constructor I am fetching a report Id. Functionality is working as expected. I am basically fetching the report Id and showing it as a link on the VF page. Now I am writing the test class for this, and not able find a way to pass the report id to the constructor of the controller from test class.

Error I am getting is

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object".

Test Class: 
.....
.....

```
AccountSalesController testSalesAccSearch =new AccountSalesController (new ApexPages.StandardController(account));
  //testSalesAccSearch.myaccid = '00O63000000KsKZEA0';
```

.....
.....

VF Code:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Reports">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!myaccid}" id="MyAcc">My Accounts</apex:outputLink><tr></tr>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller Constructor:

```
public AccountSalesController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

myaccid = [SELECT ID FROM report WHERE developerName='Active_Sales_Accounts' and FolderName = 'Sales Reports'].id;

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can change the Controller class to handle reporting scenario like this, introducing `Test.isRunningTest()` and refer any standard reports which are always be available in SFDC instance.

**Controller**

```
public AccountSalesController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    String reportName = null;
    String folderName = 'Sales Reports';
    if(Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        reportName = '<any standard SFDC report>'; //like 'Sales By Account'
    }
    else
    {
        reportName = 'Active_Sales_Accounts';
    }
    myaccid = [SELECT ID FROM report WHERE developerName=:reportName and FolderName =:folderName].id;

 }
```

**Test Class**

```
Account acct = new Account(Name='testAccount');  
insert acct;
PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
Test.setCurrentPage(page);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',acct.Id);

ApexPages.StandardController standrdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(acct);
AccountSalesController myController = new AccountSalesController(standrdcontroller);
System.assertEquals(.....);
```

Comment: Alternatively, one might use SOSL to perform a search for the record, and then in the unit test set the fixed search results to a desired value. This would leave your controller free of test code and covered 100%. I prefer to avoid having Test.isRunningTest() in live code when possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those classic scenarios where you have to use `SeeAllData=true` in your test class.

The issue is that your query -

> SELECT ID FROM report WHERE developerName='Active_Sales_Accounts' and
>   FolderName = 'Sales Reports'

is not fetching any records(means returning null) and then you are trying to access its ID which is obviously resulting into Null-pointer exception.

The bad news is that you can not create Report in Unit Test Class using apex. So only way I can think of is to use `(SeeAllData=true)` for your test class and make sure you rely on this for only the Report query and no other object.

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class MyTestClass
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: it is not needed for reports as @SeeAllData is ignored for testing of reports

Comment: I just tried it in my org and I was able to get Report data using `SeeAllData=true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Refer this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_test_reports.htm for more explanations

Comment: this is also fail during production deployment if report doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, that can be handled using `Test.isRunningTest` but any query on Report will return no rows if used with `SeeAllData=false` in a Test class. The link talks about running a report in test class i.e **report runs** always ignore the SeeAllData annotation.

Comment: Thanks Santanu Halder.  This resolved my issue. Just realized I have 2 Satanu's have answered the question :) Thanks Guys!!